# What does "max_io_queue" setting in boto3.s3.transfer.config do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

In the TransferConfig, what will increasing or decreasing max_io_queue do with boto3.transfer.download_file()??

I tried to look into source code.  It seems to relate to the queue size in  the MultipartDownloader.  If max_concurrency is fixed, I don't see how this max_io_queue would have any effect as long as max_io_queue > max_currency.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
 class TransferConfig(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 multipart_threshold=8 * MB,
                 max_concurrency=10,
                 multipart_chunksize=8 * MB,
                 num_download_attempts=5,
                 max_io_queue=100):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue synchronizes the file writes. A given thread can push any number of writes onto the queue without blocking until the queue reaches its max size. At that point, a call to `put` will block the thread until there is space remaining. If we didn't have a size limit on the queue, somebody with a fast connection and slow drive could eat up all their memory with future writes.